# ZF2 - Creating custom form view helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Some time ago, Matthew Weier O'Phinney posted [this](http://www.mwop.net/blog/217-Creating-composite-elements.html) article on his blog about creating composite form elements in Zend Framework 1.

I'm trying to create the same element for my custom library in Zend Framewor 2 but I'm having issues finding the form view helper when rendering the form.

Here is my element (DateSegmented.php):

```
<?php

namespace Si\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface;

class DateSegmented extends Element implements ViewHelperProviderInterface
{

    public function getViewHelperConfig(){
          return array( 'type' => '\Si\Form\View\Helper\DateSegment' );
     }

    protected $_dateFormat = '%year%-%month%-%day%';
    protected $_day;
    protected $_month;
    protected $_year;

    /**
     * Seed attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = array(
        'type' => 'datesegmented',
    );

    public function setDay($value)
    {
        $this->_day = (int) $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDay()
    {
        return $this->_day;
    }

    public function setMonth($value)
    {
        $this->_month = (int) $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMonth()
    {
        return $this->_month;
    }

    public function setYear($value)
    {
        $this->_year = (int) $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getYear()
    {
        return $this->_year;
    }

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        if (is_int($value)) {
            $this->setDay(date('d', $value))
                 ->setMonth(date('m', $value))
                 ->setYear(date('Y', $value));
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $date = strtotime($value);
            $this->setDay(date('d', $date))
                 ->setMonth(date('m', $date))
                 ->setYear(date('Y', $date));
        } elseif (is_array($value)
            && (isset($value['day']) 
                && isset($value['month']) 
                && isset($value['year'])
            )
        ) {
            $this->setDay($value['day'])
                 ->setMonth($value['month'])
                 ->setYear($value['year']);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid date value provided');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return str_replace(
            array('%year%', '%month%', '%day%'),
            array($this->getYear(), $this->getMonth(), $this->getDay()),
            $this->_dateFormat
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my form view helper:

```
<?php

    namespace Si\Form\View\Helper;

    use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
    use Si\Form\Element\DateSegmented as DateSegmented;
    use Zend\Form\Exception;

    class DateSegmented extends FormInput
    {
        /**
         * Render a form <input> element from the provided $element
         *
         * @param  ElementInterface $element
         * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
         * @throws Exception\DomainException
         * @return string
         */
        public function render(ElementInterface $element)
        {
            $content = "";

            if (!$element instanceof DateSegmented) {
                throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                    '%s requires that the element is of type Si\Form\Input\DateSegmented',
                    __METHOD__
                ));
            }

            $name = $element->getName();
            if (empty($name) && $name !== 0) {
                throw new Exception\DomainException(sprintf(
                    '%s requires that the element has an assigned name; none discovered',
                    __METHOD__
                ));
            }

            $view = $element->getView();
            if (!$view instanceof \Zend\View\View) {
                // using view helpers, so do nothing if no view present
                return $content;
            }

            $day   = $element->getDay();
            $month = $element->getMonth();
            $year  = $element->getYear();
            $name  = $element->getFullyQualifiedName();

            $params = array(
                'size'      => 2,
                'maxlength' => 2,
            );
            $yearParams = array(
                'size'      => 4,
                'maxlength' => 4,
            );

            $markup = $view->formText($name . '[day]', $day, $params)
                    . ' / ' . $view->formText($name . '[month]', $month, $params)
                    . ' / ' . $view->formText($name . '[year]', $year, $yearParams);

            switch ($this->getPlacement()) {
                case self::PREPEND:
                    return $markup . $this->getSeparator() . $content;
                case self::APPEND:
                default:
                    return $content . $this->getSeparator() . $markup;
            }

            $attributes            = $element->getAttributes();
            $attributes['name']    = $name;
            $attributes['type']    = $this->getInputType();
            $attributes['value']   = $element->getCheckedValue();
            $closingBracket        = $this->getInlineClosingBracket();

            if ($element->isChecked()) {
                $attributes['checked'] = 'checked';
            }

            $rendered = sprintf(
                '<input %s%s',
                $this->createAttributesString($attributes),
                $closingBracket
            );

            if ($element->useHiddenElement()) {
                $hiddenAttributes = array(
                    'name'  => $attributes['name'],
                    'value' => $element->getUncheckedValue(),
                );

                $rendered = sprintf(
                    '<input type="hidden" %s%s',
                    $this->createAttributesString($hiddenAttributes),
                    $closingBracket
                ) . $rendered;
            }

            return $rendered;
        }

        /**
         * Return input type
         *
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getInputType()
        {
            return 'datesegmented';
        }

    }
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886032/zf2-how-to-create-form-view-helper) describes adding the view helper as an invokable, but it's already being declared, as my custom library (Si) has been added to the 'StandardAutoLoader'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured this one out eventually.

Copy Zend/Form/View/HelperConfig.php to the same location in your custom library. Adjust contents to reflect your view helpers.

Add the following to an event or bootstrap in your Module.php

```
$app = $e->getApplication();
$serviceManager = $app->getServiceManager();
$phpRenderer = $serviceManager->get('ViewRenderer');

$plugins = $phpRenderer->getHelperPluginManager();
$config  = new \Si\Form\View\HelperConfig;
$config->configureServiceManager($plugins);
```

Update the 'Si' namespace with your custom one.

The 'class already exists' error was actually down to the includes at the top of my view helper file. I have updated it with:

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\Exception;
```

I also updated the instanceof statement to an absolute location due to the duplicate class names:

```
if (!$element instanceof \Si\Form\Element\DateSegmented) {
```

There were further errors in the translation from ZF1 to 2 but they are not related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand your code is: You are creating a new `Form\Element` as well as a new `Form\View\Helper`. In this case the following information is needed for you:

The `StandardAutoloader` only takes care of actually finding the classes. The declaration of the `invokables` inside the `getViewHelperConfig()` is there, so the framework knows what `Class` to load when the `ViewHelper` is called.

In your case you'd do it like this:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() 
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'dateSegmented' => 'Si\Form\View\Helper\DateSegmented'
        )
    );
}
```

Zend Framework 2 does this for it's own `ViewHelpers` inside [/Zend/Form/View/HelperConfig.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/HelperConfig.php)

Comment: Unfortunately for me, adding that generated this error `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Si\\Form\\View\\Helper\\DateSegmented because the name is already in use in /Users/oliver/Sites/xxx-qe-zf2/trunk/vendor/Si/Form/View/Helper/DateSegmented.php on line 10`

Comment: Ah i just noticed that you implement `ViewHelperProviderInterface`, that does the job for you. Unfortunately in this case i have no further clues, it's not something i've done yet, sorries.