# How to use a custom form view helper in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, view-helpers, viewhelper

I wrote a form view helper, that extends the `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox` and overwrites its [`renderOptions(...)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L235) method:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox as ZendFormMultiCheckbox;

class FormMultiCheckbox extends ZendFormMultiCheckbox 
{

    protected function renderOptions(...)
    {
        ...
        $label     = $escapeHtmlHelper($label);
        $labelOpen = $labelHelper->openTag($labelAttributes);
        switch ($labelPosition) {
            case self::LABEL_PREPEND:
                $template  = $labelOpen . $label . $labelClose . '%s';
                break;
            case self::LABEL_APPEND:
            default:
                $template  = '%s' . $labelOpen . $label . $labelClose;
                break;
        }
        $markup = sprintf($template, $input);

        $combinedMarkup[] = $markup;
        ...
    }

}
```

The next step is to register the new view helper. I'm doing this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13887355/2019043) shown:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module {

    ...

    public function getViewHelperConfig() {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'FormMultiCheckboxViewHelper' => 'MyNamespace\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Now my question: How can I make the application use my form view helper instead of `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although Andrews answer works, it's not necessary, just use the default view helper name and map it to your helper class, the application will then use your helper instead

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'formmulticheckbox' => 'MyNamespace\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox',
        ),                
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here's an example of overriding a view helper:

http://ctrl-f5.net/php/zf2-servicemanager-custom-viewhelpers/

---

Example:

```
class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        $application = $mvcEvent->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');
        $viewHelperManager->setInvokableClass('formmulticheckbox', 'MyNamespace\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should not be done that way. You should use Crisp's answer (below) to get this done right.