# Zend Framework 2 How to get individual radio button in view script?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3. Html code for the radio buttons should look like:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="search_text_source" value="title" />
        In the title
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="search_text_source" value="content" />
        In the content
    </label>
</div>
...
```

In the form, I create radio buttons as follows:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'search_text_source',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options' => array(
        'value_options' => array(
            'title' => 'In the title',
            'content' => 'In the content',
            'description' => 'In the description',
        ),
    ),  
));
```

How do I get separate each radio button in view script?

P.S.: Or any decision, which will create like html code using the form.

EDIT:

Thanks to Sam figured out. But I will leave these variants for more complex cases. During the experiments, the following happened (with standart view helper):

```
// in view script:
<?
    $this->formRadio()->setSeparator('</div><div class="radio">');
?>

<!-- some html -->

<div class="radio">
    <?php echo $this->formRadio($form->get('search_text_source')) ?>
</div>
```

Once again, thank Sam for help, without him I would not understand.

Answer (score 4):

Does anyone ever read [the documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html)? There's even a dedicated chapter for [Zend\Form\View\Helper](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formelementerrors)-Classes, that should answer all your questions.

Furthermore, since you'd probably want the TB3-Style for all your Form Elements, you may be interested in [one of the many, many TB-Modules](http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=bootstrap)

// Edit

I don't see how the documentation does not answer your question :S I believe the default output of the [`formRadio()`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formradio) viewHelper is what you're looking for anyways, so all you need is a separate div, right?

```
// any.phtml
<?=$this->form()->openTag($form);?>
<div class="radio">
    <?=$this->formRadio($form->get('radio1')); ?>
</div>
<?=$this->form()->closeTag();?>
```

// Edit2

And of course you always have the option of writing your very own `formRadio()` ViewHelper that writes out the `div` for you. There's an [easy to find SO Question, just for this very topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936804/how-to-use-a-custom-form-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2) available.

// Edit3

Feeling guilty in attitude, your ViewHelper could be as simple as this:

```
// Application\Form\View\Helper\FormRadio.php
namespace Application\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRadio as OriginalFormRadio;

class FormRadio extends OriginalFormRadio
{
    protected function renderOptions(/* include original attributes here */)
    {
        // Include 100% of Original FormMultiCheckbox Code
        // https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L147

        // Now change this one line #227 into your code
        // Instead of: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L227
        $template = '<div class="radio">' . $labelOpen . '%s%s' . $labelClose . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Then you gotta overwrite the default ViewHelper

```
// Inside Module Class
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'formradio' => 'Application\Form\View\Helper\FormRadio'
        )
    );
}
```

Additional Information: In this example i overwrite the original formRadio, rather than formMultiCheckbox. This is because I imagine TB3 would have a different CSS Class for rendering Checkboxes and not Radio elements.

Comment: @dphn Added an example now, and yes, that IS documented.

Comment: Again you do not understand the question. I would not want to upset you, but this is what I have done in the first place. Your example code displays the entire **group of radio buttons** in a separate "div". A Twitter Bootstrap 3 requires that **each radio button** is in a separate "div".

Comment: @dphn Excuse my language - it's not meant as offensive as it sounds :S I was actually mistaken in the asumption that formRadio would render only one radio element. didnt realize it extends multicheckbox already :S In this case what i pointed out in **Edit2** is what you'd be after. You would have to write your own viewhelper

Comment: Thank you probably will.

Comment: @dphn Added an third edit - explaining in lil more detail what would have to be done - it's a matter of 2 minutes max ;)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

**Form:**

```
$this->add(array(
'type'  => 'radio',
'name'  => 'gender',
'options' => array(
    'label' => 'Gender',
    'value_options' => array(
        'female' => array(
            'value' => '1',
         ),
         'male' => array(
             'value' => '2',

         ),
     ),
 ),));
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
$form->get('gender')->setLabelAttributes(array('class' => 'col-sm-4'));
echo $this->formLabel($form->get('gender'));
?>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <?php
    $element = $form->get('gender');
    $options = $element->getOptions();
    $options = $options['value_options'];
    ?>
    <div class="rdio rdio-primary">
        <input id="female" type="radio" <?php if ($element->getValue() == $options['female']['value']) echo 'checked="checked"' ?> name="<?php echo $element->getName() ?>" value="<?php echo $options['female']['value'] ?>">
        <label for="female">Female</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rdio rdio-primary">

        <input id="male"  type="radio" <?php if ($element->getValue() == $options['male']['value']) echo 'checked="checked"' ?> name="<?php echo $element->getName() ?>" value="<?php echo $options['male']['value'] ?>">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more details you can study the code given on : 
[ZF2 rendering individual radio elements with helpers](http://w3facility.org/question/zf2-rendering-individual-radio-elements-with-helpers/)